# polkadot js how to send all the funds

Tags: polkadot-js

I am trying to send all the available funds using polkadot.js how does one do that?

I have seen in the polkadot-ui one can purge the sender account or send all available funds and am wondering how can i translate that into code so I don't have little funds leftover and burned due to minimal extrinsic deposits.

Answer (score 3):

You have  the [`balances.transferAll`](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics#transferalldest-multiaddress-keep_alive-bool) method that you should call with a `keep_alive = false` so it doesn't leave the existential deposit.